# Лишний отступ в HTML!

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, почему между последней строкой списка и текстом чёрным внизу есть такой большой отступ. В firebug не показывает тот отступ, код полностью валиден. Появилась горизонтальная полоса прокрутки. Может быть проблема в том, что все время двигал блоки (position: relative;) на большое расстояние? Буду очень благодарен за помощь, а то долго не могу решить проблему, чтобы писать дальше. И еще, этот текст сам выравнивается приблизительно по центру, с учетом того, что я его не выравнивал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>The Future of the Planet</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
    <div id="logoimage">
        <img src="images/logo1.png" alt="logo" />
    </div>
    <div id="logotext">
    <p><span>Далеке</span> майбутнє</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="topmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Головна</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>Галерея</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>Пророцтва</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>Про автора</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>Зворотній зв'язок</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="search">
    <form action="#" method="post" id="formpost">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="" value="Пошук..."    onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Пошук...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Пошук...') this.value='';" class="inputblock" />
            <input type="submit" name="" value="" class="submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="searchyear">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>21 століття</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>22 століття</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>23 століття</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>Далеке майбутнє</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="border-none">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Після 10000 року</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="year">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">2017</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2018</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2020</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2022</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2025</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2028</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2032</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2036</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2041</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2047</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2055</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2060</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2069</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2075</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2079</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2085</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2095</a></li>       
    </ul>
    <br />
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">2110</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2120</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2130</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2140</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2150</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2160</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2170</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2180</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2190</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2200</a></li>   
    </ul>
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">2210</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2230</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2240</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2250</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2260</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2280</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2300</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">2310</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2350</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2500</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2600</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2700</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2880</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3000</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3500</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4000</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">10000</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">11800</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">12000</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">19500</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">22000</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">30000</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">35000</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">42000</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">52000</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">100000</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>ПРОБЛЕМНЫЙ ТЕКСТ</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background: url("../images/bg.jpg") repeat;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1060px) {
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1060px;
}
}

@font-face {
font-family: "AvdiraBoldItalic";
  src: url("../fonts/AvdiraBoldItalic.eot");
  src: local('O'), 
  url("../fonts/AvdiraBoldItalic.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
  url("../fonts/AvdiraBoldItalic.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../fonts/AvdiraBoldItalic.ttf") format("truetype"), 
  url("../fonts/AvdiraBoldItalic.svg#PT Serif") format("svg");
}

#logo {
display: block;
height: 174px;
}

#logoimage {
position: relative;
top: 20px;
}

#logotext {
position: relative;
left: 150px;
top: -127px;
}

#logotext p {
font-family: AvdiraBoldItalic, Arial;
font-size: 30pt;
color: #fff;
}

#logotext p span {
color: #00bac6;
}

#topmenu {
background-color: #218cc8;
margin: 30px 0 0 20px;
}

#topmenu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#topmenu ul li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin-right: 10px;
}

#topmenu ul li a {
color: #fff;
font-size: 120%;
display: block;
padding: 10px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 20px;
}

#topmenu ul li.active a, #topmenu ul li a:hover {
background-color: #125c87;
}

#search {
width: 200px;
height: 37px;
float: right;
margin: 3px 10px 0 0;
}

#search input {
float: left;
border: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
width: 50px;
height: 36px;
padding: 0 37px 1px 15px;
background-color: #f0f4f4;
color: #5d5d5d;
font-family: Verdana, Arial;
outline: none;
border-radius: 7px;
font-size: 8pt;
overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="submit"] {
width: 26px;
height: 29px;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: -37px;
background: url("../images/lupa.png") no-repeat;
margin-top: 5px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
background-color: #d4dada;
width: 140px;
background-position: left 30px center;
text-indent: 0;
white-space: normal;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#searchyear {
margin-top: 100px;
display: block;
width: 160px;
height: 220px;
}

#searchyear li {
margin-bottom: 15px;
list-style: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#searchyear li a {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #afb2bc;
}

#searchyear li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

#searchyear li.border-none {
border-bottom: none;
}

#year {
position: relative;
top: -253px;
left: 150px;
height: 100px;
}

#year ul {
margin-bottom: 31px;
}

#year li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
padding-bottom: 14px;
}

#year li.last {
border-bottom: none;
}

#year li  a {
text-decoration: none;
margin-right: 10px;
color: #afb2bc;
}

#year li  a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить на html5 шаблон https://www.sitepoint.com/a-minimal-html-document-html5-edition/ и проверьте кодировку документа, должна быть utf-8

Comment: XelaNimed, ничего не изменилось. Тут проблема с отступами, но не могу понять где и с какими.

Comment: Добавил сейчас после списков <div class="clear"></div>; .class { clear: both}. теперь выровнялось, как нужно, по левому краю, но вод поднять не могу! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в блоке `<div id="year">...</div>`.
У него задано правило `position: relative; top: -253px;`

Насколько я помню, при указании значения свойства `position: relative` элемент смещается относительно своего положения в документе, но при этом место, на котором он должен находится остается зарезервировано за ним. То есть пустое пространство, которое Вы наблюдаете, это место под блок `<div id="year">...</div>`

Comment: Иван Цыганенко, Да, спасибо огромное, я уже понял. А что мне сделать? Я когда изменяю высоту блока year на 1px, ничего не меняется.(

Comment: Я не верстальщик, но может быть имеет смысл попробовать использовать абсолютное позиционирование.
#year {
    position: absolute;
    top: 255px;
    left: 320px;
}

Comment: Иван Цыганенко, Вы гений, спасибо! :)